# Most efficient way to append 1000s of dom elemens

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

I have the following `<template>` element that I need to append 1000s of times:

```
<template id="template-row">
    <div id="div-row">
        <label class="is_visible checkbox-container">
          <input type="checkbox" name="cb_active_column" id="checkbox_id" /> <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <div draggable='true' class="row_draggable">
            <div class="row_data">
              <div class="row_data_details">
                <div class="row-left">
                  <!--<div id="colon">:</div>-->
                  <div id='name' class="column_name hidden"></div>
                  <div id='alias_name' class="column_name"></div>
                  <div id="v_name" class="column_name colon"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="row_icon_info">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-2.033 16.01c.564-1.789 1.632-3.932 1.821-4.474.273-.787-.211-1.136-1.74.209l-.34-.64c1.744-1.897 5.335-2.326 4.113.613-.763 1.835-1.309 3.074-1.621 4.03-.455 1.393.694.828 1.819-.211.153.25.203.331.356.619-2.498 2.378-5.271 2.588-4.408-.146zm4.742-8.169c-.532.453-1.32.443-1.761-.022-.441-.465-.367-1.208.164-1.661.532-.453 1.32-.442 1.761.022.439.466.367 1.209-.164 1.661z" style="fill:#ccc;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"/></svg>
            </div>
              <span id="sort_order"></span>
              <select id="column_aggregate" class="string"></select>
              <select id="column_period" class="string"></select>
              <select id="column_show_type" class="string"></select>
              <select id="column_search_type" class="string"></select>
              <select id="column_data_format" class="string"></select>
              <div id="filter_group">
                  <span>filter by</span>
                  <select id="filter_by"></select>
                  <div id="filter_subtotal_group">
                      <span>in</span>
                      <select id="filter_subtotal"></select>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <select id="filter_operator"></select>
              <input id="filter_operand" placeholder="Value" />
              <div id="rename_group">
                  <input id="rename_field" placeholder="Rename" />
                  <span id="rename_exclamation" hidden>&#x26A0;</span>
                  <span id="rename_submit">&#10003;</span>
              </div>
              <span id="row_exclamation" hidden>&#x26A0;</span>
              <span id='row_close'>&#x2715;</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Currently this takes about 3s to add the 1000+ templates. What would be the most performant way to do this -- i.e., I'm hoping that this could be added in 'one-go' in under a few hundred milliseconds if that is possible.

Comment: How are you adding/appending this to the DOM?

Comment: Fastest way is to only load in the dom the ones that can be seen on screen.

Comment: @JaredFarrish that's similar to the canvas-approach? Is there a 'virutualized library' or something to make this easy to do?

Comment: @JonathanLam tried shadow-root and innerHTML.

Comment: We had a similar issue with a table we appended with thousands of activated content data rows.We used Vue's `v-if` to control what was loaded (`v-show` loads but hides), however we expanded rows. Scrollspy could help if it were a long table. You would just have to front run what's next to appear.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks. `v-if` sounds perfect, but we're not using a framework...do you know of any framework-agnostic approaches that do something similar?

Comment: It probably matters what you mean by "loaded in a few hundred milliseconds", if whether that means the browser doesn't freeze, or that literally everything is available.

Comment: You can use insertAdjacentText() also.